# iOS Realm Update Object In Block

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, realm

I'm working on integrating Realm into an iOS app, and am beginning to write a class to handle all of my Realm stuff and was writing a convenience method to update any RLMObject dynamically.

In their docs, updating an object is as simple as:

```
- (void)someMethod {
    [self.realm beginWriteTransaction];
    someObject.name = @"New name";
    someObject.somethingElse = @"New something";
    [self.realm commitWriteTransaction];
}
```

I'm wondering if the following would work/have any negative consequences when you mix Realm with GCD stuff:

```
- (void)updateObjectAndCommitWithUpdateBlock:(dispatch_block_t)updateBlock {
    [self.realm beginWriteTransaction];
    updateBlock();
    [self.realm commitWriteTransaction];
}
```

Then in another class do the following:

```
- (void)someMethod {
    [[RealmManager sharedInstance] updateObjectAndCommitWithUpdateBlock:^{
        someObject.name = @"New name";
        someObject.somethingElse = @"New something";
    }];
}
```

Comment: You will have thread problems, because that way is not thread safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From realm.io:

> Sharing RLMRealm instances across threads is not supported.

So, you need to use

```
RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
```

in each thread.

If you prefer blocks, use standard one:

```
[realm transactionWithBlock:^{
    //your code
}];
```

Comment: Ahh I didn't get that far in the docs - that is a much easier/safer solution. Cheers!